# jquery radio group selector not changing value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to react to clicking on my radio button group. For some reason, its not working as expected. Every time I click on one of the radio buttons, the returned value is the same, the default value (ie: U.S. postal delivery).

here's my jquery:

```
var deliveryMethod = $('input[name="delivery-method"]');
deliveryMethod.click(function() {
    if(deliveryMethod.val() === "U.S. postal delivery") {
        console.log('yay!');
    }
});
```

here's my markup:

```
<div class="form-radios"><div class="form-item" id="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery"><input type="radio" id="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery" name="delivery-method" value="U.S. postal delivery"  checked="checked"  class="form-radio" /> U.S. postal delivery</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-delivery-method-Canadian-postal-delivery-wrapper">
<label class="option" for="edit-delivery-method-Canadian-postal-delivery"><input type="radio" id="edit-delivery-method-Canadian-postal-delivery" name="delivery-method" value="Canadian postal delivery"   class="form-radio" /> Canadian postal delivery</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-delivery-method-International-postal-delivery-wrapper">
<label class="option" for="edit-delivery-method-International-postal-delivery"><input type="radio" id="edit-delivery-method-International-postal-delivery" name="delivery-method" value="International postal delivery"   class="form-radio" /> International postal delivery</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-delivery-method-Digital-delivery-wrapper">
<label class="option" for="edit-delivery-method-Digital-delivery"><input type="radio" id="edit-delivery-method-Digital-delivery" name="delivery-method" value="Digital delivery"   class="form-radio" /> Digital delivery</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the getter version of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), if the jQuery object you call it on contains multiple DOM element references, `.val()` will return the value of only the first in the collection. You need to get the value of only the `checked` input element.

It may be more appropriate to listen for the change event of your checkboxes, since if the one being clicked is already selected, it will still invoke your functionality.

You can then use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) together with the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo selector to return only the checked radio `input` and get the value of it:

```
var deliveryMethod = $('input[name="delivery-method"]');
deliveryMethod.change(function() {
    if(deliveryMethod.filter(':checked').val() === "U.S. postal delivery") {
        console.log('yay!');
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5gxv761/)

Comment: can you explain to me why this answer (which also does work, and is more complete because it does use 'change') doesn't require the use of $(this), as the other two answers do?

Comment: Instead, it takes the jQuery object you currently have and filters out the currently checked radio button using the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo selector. There will only ever be one match for this since grouped radio buttons can only have 1 checked at a time.

Comment: it is just a longer way to write `$(this)` :p

Comment: @Banana It's really not. The two aren't equivalent.

Comment: @George in his scenario, it is. because he captures click events on the radio buttons. your way would be more appropriate in case he changes the radio values programatically and not by clicking them.

Comment: @Banana Oh in *this* scenario, they return the same object. I thought you meant in general. (:

Answer (score 4):

Because it returns an array of elements, and you are only checking the value of the first item. when handling arrays in jquery, you need to take the value of `$(this)`, the element in the array which has triggered the click function:

```
var deliveryMethod = $('input[name="delivery-method"]');
deliveryMethod.click(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "U.S. postal delivery") {
        console.log('yay!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have several elements with the name `delivery-method`, so ywhen you do the first assignment, you get an array of elements, but the click function only fires on the first one.  Write it like this:

```
$('input[name="delivery-method"]').each(function() {

   $(this).click(function() {
    //do what you did here
   });
});
```

Comment: can you tell me why using each() is more appropriate than not using it, as @banana above showed in his post? Are they equivalent?

Comment: @user1015214 http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/  each iterates the entire array, assigning that click event to each input with the attribute `name` as "delivery-method"  It's essentially the same as other answers here, but I like using each personally, as it comes in handy in other places.  So I keep my code consistant by using anywhere where I have an variable array of objects